# How do I compare a text response from HTTPrequest to some other text in flex 3 for a conditional?

Tags: php, flex3, httprequest, conditional-statements

I am building a form in Flex Builder 3 that is supposed to POST to a php document via an `HTTPrequest` and come back with a text response. Using `Alert.show()` I have verified that the `HTTPrequest` is sending the POSTed data and the response is coming back correctly. I am trying to use the response in a conditional statement in order to preform the next set of operations.

```
<![CDATA[

import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
import mx.controls.Alert;

public var resCreate:String = new String;

private function returnCreate(event:ResultEvent):void{
resCreate = String(event.result);       
resultCreation();       
}

private function resultCreation():void{
Alert.show(resCreate);
if (resCreate == "Y"){
    currentState = "LogIn";
}
    else {      
    Alert.show("User already exists.");
    currentState = "NewEmployee";
    }
}

]]>

</mx:Script>

<mx:HTTPService 
        id="createSend" 
        url="create.php" 
        useProxy="false" 
        method="POST" 
        resultFormat="text" 
        result ="returnCreate(event)">
    <mx:request xmlns="">
        <username>{textinput9.text}</username>      
        <password>{textinput13.text}</password>    
    </mx:request>
</mx:HTTPService>
```

I have an `Alert.show()` to see what is in my variable. It is the response from the `HTTPrequest`, and it says "Y" when the new user is created or "N" when the user already exists in the database. This is working properly. The first time I create a new user, I get a "Y", and when I attempt to create that user again I get "N." I have also done this:

```
 Alert.show(String(resCreate == "Y"));
```

and I received a Boolean `true` or `false` depending on if the answer was "`Y`" or "`N`". This is how I know that my script is recognizing the response, but it is simply refusing to do so within the conditional statement. When I attempt to use it in the conditional, only the code within the "else" fires as if resCreate is never recognized as being "Y" at all. The Alert belies this and when I check my database, the new user has been created successfully. What am I doing wrong? I have gotten this same type of thing to work in other applications I've written, but not in this one.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. Have you tried to clean the workspace? Maybe it is still using an older version of the code when compiling.

Comment: I figured it out. The response was coming back with an extra space. What I thought was "Y" was actually "Y ". I used this to fix it: resCreate = resCreate.replace(" ",""); Thanks! :)